# Force Visual Studio (2010-2013) to save user settings without quitting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

My VS crashes sometimes because of an Addin i must use.

After each crash, the project configuration changes back to what it was when it was 1st opened. Also all "old" tabs are reopened, and the "new" ones are not.

Any way to force VS to save the user settings file often ?
An addin can do it maybe ?

Comment: And btw, force Windows to save the desktop icon positions between each windows crash (it crashes when testing overcloking stability).